# Need help fixing a ValueError of and 'i' index

Tags: python

So I'm making this code that uses strings to cipher a given phrase with a given key (I can't use the preset functions in python to do it). I believe I've got the idea of how to do it but I;m experiencing this error that I can't figure out how to fix. My code is the following.

```
def inputForChipher():
    input1 = False
    input2 = False
    while input1 == False:
        string = input('Enter the message: ')
        input1 = verifyString(string)
    while input2 == False:
        key = input('Enter the key you want to use: ')
        input2 = verifyString(key)
    print(cipherWithKey(string, key))

def cipherWithKey(string, key):
    string = string.lower()
    key = key.lower()
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    count = 0
    newCode = ''
    for i in string:
        if i == '':
            count = 0
            newCode += i
        else:
            if count > (len(key)-1):
                count = 0
            value1 = letters.index(i) + 1
            value2 = letters.index(key[count]) + 1
            num = value1 + value2
            if num > 26:
                num -= 26
            newCode += letters[num-1]
            count += 1
    return newCode
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\funciones.py", line 29, in cipherWithKey
    value1 = letters.index(i) + 1
ValueError: substring not found
```

I know what causes this error, but I'm not sure of why I'm getting it in this case.

Comment: What are the parameters that you're passing into the function?

Comment: I will add that part

Comment: Just updated the code

Comment: What does `verifyString` do?

Comment: and what are your inputs

Comment: Sorry, the code is originally written in Spanish and verificarLetras escaped me. verifyString basically checks that there aren't numbers or characters other than letters on the inputs.

Comment: Ok, what are some example strings that you supply that cause your code to fail?

Comment: Anything with a whitespace

Comment: For example if I input 'tarea' as my message with 'tango' as the key I get the output I should get, but if I input 'tarea de' I get the error.

Comment: Should any character that isn't a lowercase alphabetic character simply be itself in the output?

Comment: Yes, only letters have to change.

Comment: well its clear , in your input 'tarea de' you are passing space in your input ( string varible) which is not in letters variable and it fails in that line.

Comment: so what should I change in order to allow other characters on the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well its clear , in your input 'tarea de' you are passing space in your input ( string varible) which is not in letters variable and it fails in that line.

you can add the possible characters to your letters variable like :

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
```

alternatively you can use `string module` to provide the full list of whitespaces

```
import string as st 
letters = st.ascii_lowercase + st.whitespace
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in another way? I have a code in this same assignment that works with spaces but uses the same letters variable, but I'm not sure of what causes it.

Comment: @JeremyK12 , I don't think so , that code you are mentioning needs to be examined too. but your problem definitely is because of this .also see updated answer

Comment: I see, then I will try this. Thank you very much!